# Can Electron apps bundle VueJS, MongoDB, etc. or do they need to be installed on users PCs for the app to run?

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, electron

I've been looking for over an hour and can't find an answer on this, not even on docs and the ones I have found are just too confusing. I want to know before starting to use Electron if the built apps with electron-bundler or any other bundlers can bundle Vue & MongoDB, so that when a user installs the Electron app - he doesn't need those libraries installed on his computer, but can use the app straight ahead.

I know it's a noob question, sorry, but I'm just too confused about all of this.

Comment: Not recommending it and pretty sure there are more: https://github.com/huangruichang/mongo-vue-electron. In short, it can be done.

Comment: Why would you not recommend it and could you point me to a resource where I can see how it can be done? @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: I don't recommend it because I haven't used it, so I don't know if it's good or bad. Maybe a better choice of words would have been: *"I don't endorse it"*. I do use Vue + Electron at work on a very large project. It's MongoDB that I don't know about. However, Electron is just a wrapper and doesn't care what you put inside. All the user needs to do is open the application and it all works, pretty much like it would on a web server.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the Vue explanation @AndreiGheorghiu, now I got all the pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue, like all other Client SPA frameworks, is designed to build static assets that can run "standalone" in a browser. So it is straightforward bundling those assets in an electron app.

MongoDB, like most Server databases, is totally the opposite: it is designed to be installed once, run as a service, and Clients (including your electron app) connect to it (usually through a network). So it is very difficult bundling it in a standalone installer, not even talking about a portable app. The repo linked by Andrei Gheorghiu is an example of such architecture: it does not bundle the Mongo service, but connects to it.

If you look for "electron database" keywords, you will find plenty resources about this subject. The key is to look for self-contained / embedded databases, like SQLite. There are also some NoSQL alternatives, e.g. NeDB.